# Communicating in and out of Flash , AMF or XML?

Tags: flash

I need to be communication between Flash and The Server or javascript. I'm wondering which one would be better AMF or XML ? ( I'm in the facebook canvas page )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AMF is better because it does serialization and de-serialization of ActionScript objects. In AMF a boolean remains a boolean from the server to the Flash app. Plus you can even send XML in AMF.

Check out the AMF spec:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/1114283/amf3_spec_05_05_08.pdf

All the major server side technologies had Adobe AMF support (PHP, Python, DotNet, etc...)